# Chart.js, PHP and JSON loop issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, chart.js

I am trying to create a dashboard that will show some data from a database. Right now I am using a separate JSON encoded file named "data.php". I am using a jQuery Ajax request for this data to populate a Chart.js chart.

I have also been following [an example similar to this](https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-bar-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php)

At the moment I am running into an issue seen here on my app.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://{redacted ip}/swordtest/data.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {

            //var myData = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(data);
            var teamid = [];
            var teamName = [];
            var  ticketCount = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                teamid.push("ID " + data[i].id);
                teamName.push(data[i].name);
                ticketCount.push(data[i].count);
            }

            console.log(data);

            var chartData = {
                lables: teamName,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label : 'Teams',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75, 1)',
                        hoverborderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75, 1)',
                        data: ticketCount
                    }
                ] 
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");


            var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartData
            });

        }, 
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What is happening though is that when I try to loop through the JSON object to separate the id's, names of the teams and amount of tickets, it will loop through the id continuously and give me this:

```
teamid = (1) ["ID undefined", "ID undefined"]
```

It will also add one and keep saying undefined. When I put breakpoints in the code it seems to only loop through the id as well. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

*UPDATE*
one thing to mention is that the data that I am getting from my data.php is a little different looking than the example I am working from (the link mentioned above). when I print the data it comes in this format:

```
data = "{"playerid":"1","score":"10"},{  "playerid":"2","score":"40"},{ "playerid":"3","score":"20"},{  "playerid":"4","score":"9"},{  "playerid":"5","score":"20"}"
```

Where in the example it looks like:

```
[{"playerid":"1","score":"10"},{  "playerid":"2","score":"40"},{ "playerid":"3","score":"20"},{  "playerid":"4","score":"9"},{  "playerid":"5","score":"20"}]
```

Different with brackets and without. I had a friend just try taking out the double quotes, replacing them with single quotes and wrapping the whole JSON in brackets. It seemed to start working then. I am guessing it has something to do with the way the JSON is getting formatted in my data.php.

Comment: Can you please so the code for data.php as well. I am currently creating a dashboard using Chartjs as well, so been using it recently for this exact purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the `dataType` property to the object literal that is the argument of the `ajax()` function. As you are getting a JSON from PHP, the property should have `"json"` as its value.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
         // ...
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("AJAX ERROR",textStatus,errorThrown,jqXHR);
    }
});
```

I tested with this PHP file.

test.php

```
<?php
  echo '[{"id":"1", "name":"John Doe", "count":"7"},{"id":"2", "name":"ABC", "count":"5"},{"id":"3", "name":"XYZ", "count":"29"}]';
?>
```